# Jquery - Get the latest element in a div

Tags: jquery

somethings
            

            
                somethings
            

             
                somethings
            

            
                somethings
            

            
                somethings

How can select (with jquery) the latest element of this div with classname trackon? (in this case, the #trackline1)
cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.tlcontent').children().last()
```

If you just what the last thing in `content`, try:

```
$('.content :last')
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Kgp2u/

Comment: uhm great! but i forgot 1 question : if i need only the last children with class "trackon" ? :)

Comment: @markzzz - In that case you can use `$('.content .trackon:last')`. jQuery selectors can be very powerful, I suggest you read a little on the subject, it can save you quite a few minutes of coding `:)`

Answer (score 3):

```
var latest = $('.tlcontent div:last');
latest.css({color:'red'});
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UsLZm/)

Comment: tnx!!! and if i want the last id on tlcontent only for div with class "trackon" ?

Answer (score 0):

$(".tlcontent div").last();